# load an animation in a cubereflection mapping in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made an environment map and put an animation inside. I am trying to make the animation runs but it's no t possible.

Can someone help me please?

```
    <script src="sources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


    <script src="sources/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="sources/js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var stats, loader;

        var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

        var mesh;

        var pointLight;

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var height = 300; // of camera frustum

        var r = 0.0;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            //

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - height * aspect, height * aspect, height, - height, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1500;
            scene.add( camera );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.enableZoom = true;
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            // lights

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x111111 );
            scene.add( ambientLight );

            pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0x030303, 0.5 );
            pointLight.position.z = 2500;
            scene.add( pointLight );

            var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x030303, 1 );
            camera.add( pointLight2 );

            var pointLight3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xe8e4e4, 0.5 );
            pointLight3.position.x = - 1000;
            pointLight3.position.z = 1000;
            scene.add( pointLight3 );

            // env map

            var imgAr = [
                      'sources/instagram2/image1.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image2.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image3.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image4.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image5.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image6.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image7.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image8.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image9.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image10.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image11.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image12.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image13.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image14.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image15.jpg',
                      'sources/instagram2/image16.jpg'
                    ];

            var urls = imgAr.sort(function(){return .6 - Math.random()}).slice(0,6);



            var reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls, THREE.CubeReflectionMapping );


            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "sources/models/animated/horse.js", function ( geometry ) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    morphTargets: true,
                    overdraw: 0.5,
                    envMap: reflectionCube,
                    combine: THREE.AddOperation,
                    reflectivity: 1,
                    shininess: 0,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );
                mesh.rotation.x = 0.5;
                mesh.rotation.y = 0.5;
                mesh.position.y = -170;
                mesh.position.x = 0;
                scene.add( mesh );

                mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );

                var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence( 'gallop', geometry.morphTargets, 30 );
                mixer.addAction( new THREE.AnimationAction( clip ).warpToDuration( 1 ) );

            } );

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

            camera.left = - height * aspect;
            camera.right = height * aspect;
            camera.top = height;
            camera.bottom = - height;

            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        //background texture

        var backgroundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture
        }));

        backgroundMesh .material.depthTest = false;
        backgroundMesh .material.depthWrite = false;

        //background scene and the camera
        var backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();
        var backgroundCamera = new THREE.Camera();
        backgroundScene .add(backgroundCamera );
        backgroundScene .add(backgroundMesh );


        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            controls.update();

            render();

            stats.update();

        }

        var radius = 600;

        var prevTime = Date.now();

        function render() {


            pointLight.position.x = 2500 * Math.cos( r );
            pointLight.position.z = 2500 * Math.sin( r );

            r = 0;

            if ( mixer ) {

                var time = Date.now();

                mixer.update( ( time - prevTime ) * 0.001 );

                prevTime = time;

            }

            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(backgroundScene , backgroundCamera );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error?  If there's not an error, what happens when you try to run the animation?

Comment: Hello Devlin. I'm not receiving an error. When i run the the animation i can see the geometry but it doesn't move.

Comment: What happens if you declare the mixer var at the top, after mesh? It looks like mixer might only exist in the callback scope?

Comment: I already declared the mixer var at the top and it still doesn't work...

Comment: so mixer.update is being called ok?

Comment: Yes i called inside function animate ( ) {

Comment: now I see that the problem is inside the function render() is something with the mixer i think but I still trying to change everything an I can't fix the problem